# Expressjs Pagination Redirect

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, pagination

I have a pagination setup where my feed is displayed with the index route path `/` and then additional pages are accessed with `/feed/:pageNumber`. I have no issue with the pagination delivering the next and previous records, but when I want to have the ability on the last previousPage click to redirect to the `/` path since this has the most recent records. I tried to use res.redirect('/') on the else statement, but I get an error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`. Is there a better approach to redirect to the home on the last previousPage click?

E.x. User is on '/', clicks Next and is sent to '/feed/2'. When User clicks Previous then they should be brought back to '/'. If they are on /feed/3,4,5,etc/ then it will bring the user to one less than the current parameter value.

Section I'm trying to fix:

```
if(req.params.pageNumber > 2){
                    res.locals.previous = true;
                    res.locals.previousPage = req.params.pageNumber - 1;
                } else {
                    res.locals.previous = true;
                    res.locals.previous = res.redirect('/');
                }
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {{> app/app-head}}
</head>
<body>
    {{> app/app-navigation}}

    <div class="container"> 
        <h1 class="page-title-header">Activity Feed</h1>
            {{> app/card}}
    </div>
    {{#if previous}}
    <a href="/feed/{{previousPage}}">Previous Page</a>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if secondPage}}
    <a href="/feed/{{secondPage}}">Next Page</a>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if next}}
    <a href="/feed/{{nextPage}}">Third Page</a>
    {{/if}}
</body>
```

Routes:

```
/*====   /  ====*/

appRoutes.route('/') 

    .get(function(req, res){

        models.Card.findAll({
            order: 'cardDate DESC',
            include: [{
                model: models.User,
                where: { organizationId: req.user.organizationId },
                attributes: ['organizationId', 'userId']
            }],
            limit: 10
        }).then(function(card){

            function feedLength(count){
                if (count >= 10){
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            res.render('pages/app/high-level-activity-feed.hbs',{
                card: card,
                user: req.user,
                secondPage: feedLength(card.length)
            });
        });
    })

    .post(function(req, res){
        models.Card.create({
            card: req.body.cardDate,
            userId: req.user.userId
        }).then(function() { 
            res.redirect('/app');
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
        })
    });

appRoutes.route('/feed/:pageNumber')

    .get(function(req, res){

        function paginationPage(count){
            if(count == 2){
                return 10;
            } else {
                return (count - 1) * 10;
            }
        };
        var skip = parseInt(req.params.pageNumber);

        models.Card.findAll({
            order: 'cardDate DESC',
            include: [{
                model: models.User,
                where: { organizationId: req.user.organizationId },
                attributes: ['organizationId', 'userId']
            }],
            offset: paginationPage(skip),
            limit: 10
        }).then(function(annotation){
                if(annotation.length == 10){

                    res.locals.next = true;
                    res.locals.nextPage = parseInt(req.params.pageNumber) + 1;
                    console.log('This is the next page pagination: ' + res.locals.nextPage);
                }

                if(req.params.pageNumber > 2){
                    res.locals.previous = true;
                    res.locals.previousPage = req.params.pageNumber - 1;
                } else {
                    res.locals.previous = true;
                    res.locals.previous = res.redirect('/');
                }
            res.render('pages/app/high-level-activity-feed.hbs',{
                card: card,
                user: req.user
            });
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is two-fold:

- your template always prefixes the *previous page* link with `/feed/`:

  ```
  <a href="/feed/{{previousPage}}">Previous Page</a>
  ```
- `res.redirect('/')` performs an *actual* redirect from within your Express server (it does not produce a link, or a client-side javascript)

A possible solution would be to add a third state to your template:

```
{{#if backHome}}
<a href="/">Previous Page</a>
{{/if}}
```

And in your server code:

```
if (req.params.pageNumber > 2) {
  res.locals.previous = true;
  res.locals.previousPage = req.params.pageNumber - 1;
} else {
  res.locals.backHome = true;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks @robertklep for the help and explanation.